# Is it possible to use HTTP basic authentication within an iframe?

Tags: iframe, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

I have a directory that uses htpasswd for authentication. The authentication works fine in a normal browser window but displays an "Authorization Required" error when the directory or any file within it are embedded using an iframe. Is it not possible to use htpasswd authentication within an iframe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [basic authentication in iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639280/basic-authentication-for-a-url-in-an-iframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic authentication for a url in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639280/basic-authentication-for-a-url-in-an-iframe)