# Preventing direct access to a page, but allowing iframe embedding

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Can I prevent direct access to a file, but allow that page to be embedded in an other page as an iframe?

I am using Apache and php on the serverside, and the file to be included is on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the best solution (as some browsers or routers remove it) but you could use the `HTTP_REFERER` server value?

Something like:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== 'http://my-domain.com/page-x') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
    exit;
}
//rest of code here
```

Comment: I thought about this, but when when viewing on the browser, and right clicking on the iframe and choose to open just the frame, it actually detects the referred as the main containing file, and hence still displays the frame by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you cannot. Either you make your page available to everyone, or to no-one.

You can protect the page via basic authentication in order to restrict he users who can access it, however who accesses it will need to know the credentials for the page. There is a SO question on a topic like this: [Basic authentication for a url in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639280/basic-authentication-for-a-url-in-an-iframe).